# Rigidbody2D with freeze rotation stutters when manually rotated

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a rigidbody2D with freeze rotation on, and I'd like to manually rotate the rigidbody. Since `MoveRotation` doesn't work when the rotation is frozen, I'm using the `RigidBody2D.rotation` field itself. Here's my movement code below:

```cs
private void FixedUpdate() {
    rb2D.rotation += turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
```

However, I've noticed that this causes stuttering in the latest unity versions (v2022.2) compared to older versions like (v2017). Does anyone know how to fix this?

I noticed disabling rotation freeze and using `MoveRotation` fixes the stuttering, but then objects are now free to rotate when they collide, which is behavior I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Try this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.Sleep.html. Also, there's a physics debugger window.